# rails 3 project, how to use tinyurl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinyurl

Is anyone aware of how to get inyurls in a ruby 192/rails 3 app?

I thought this would be simple... installed the gem 'shorturl' also added it to my Gemfile, did bundle install, and it all looked fine except when I run rails console it immediately throws an error so it's apparently not compatible with ruby 192/rails3.

```
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require': c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/shorturl-0.8.8/lib/short
url.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
                 when :post: http.post(@action, "#{@field...
```

I considered using Bitly, the gem installed fine, but bitly makes PUBLIC all of the urls you shorten... really not a good idea since we're providing urls to private links.

Answer (score 0):

The `when x:` syntax is not compatible with Ruby 1.9 (you have to use `when x then`). Contact the gem author or fix it yourself by forking the repo. Alternatively you can use Ruby 1.8.7 for this.

Comment: thanks but I dont need another project, and since the gem hasnt been updated I'm pretty sure it's not maintained. Thought maybe there was another get, or a way to do it by doing an api call.